# Declaring and using variables in triggers

Tags: mysql, trigger

I have been testing something with triggers today, but I am stuck with it and I do not have any idea what is causing my problem.

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `pucko`$$

CREATE TRIGGER `after_delete_Alien`
AFTER DELETE ON `Alien` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN       
    DECLARE vapenid INT;
    DECLARE alien_count INT;
    DECLARE rymdskepp_count INT;

    SET vapenid = (SELECT vapen FROM `Alien_Använder_Vapen` WHERE idAlien = OLD.idAlien);

    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = vapenid; // Debug, this shows that vapenid is null?

    DELETE FROM `Alien_Använder_Vapen` WHERE idAlien = OLD.idAlien;

    SET alien_count = (SELECT count(*) FROM `Alien_Använder_Vapen` WHERE vapen = vapenid);
    SET rymdskepp_count = (SELECT count(*) FROM `Rymdskepp_Använder_Vapen` WHERE vapen = vapenid);


    if(alien_count < 1 && rymdskepp_count < 1) THEN
        DELETE FROM `vapen` WHERE idVapen = vapenid;
    END IF;
END$$
```

The problem I am having is when `vapenid` is/should be set. I know that there is an alien with id "abc". I know that there is a `vapen` with id 1. In `Alien_Använder_Vapen` there is a row with `alienId` abc and `vapen` as 1. I use the `SIGNAL` to debug a bit what the value of `vapenid` is, and mySQL returns

> delete from Alien where idAlien = "abc"    Error Code: 1231. Variable 'MESSAGE_TEXT' can't be set to the value of 'NULL'

This makes me think that NULL is returned from the query in `vapenid`, but that doesn't make sense, as `SELECT vapen FROM`Alien_Använder_Vapen`WHERE idAlien = 'abc'` in a normal query returns 1 correctly.

I've been trying to figure this out for quite some time now but I just can't see what I'm doing wrong. Is my syntax or logic wrong/weird?

Comment: Do you have a foreign key on that column referencing the Alien.idAlien column and set to ON DELETE CASCADE?

Comment: @Mr.Brownstone D'oh I thought I removed that, thank you, it all works now :D. Stupid mistakes you make when you try for too long...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my comment above, the chances are that you have a foreign key that is set to delete on cascade. This is what is causing your lookup to fail.

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Put it like this:

```
declare int_value int default 1;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER call_trigger
 AFTER INSERT ON ticket
 FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
 declare v_index int default 1;
 while v_index <= 15 do
   **YOUR QUERY**
   set v_index := v_index + 1;
 end while;
END
$$
DELIMITER;
```

Source: http://findoutanswer.com/tag/mysql

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Please have a look at the help about formatting posts properly: http://dba.stackexchange.com/editing-help  Also you should include some explanation why and how this will help with the original problem.  Thanks.